# How to set up Dreamweaver to use CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, dreamweaver

I am using dreamweaver cs5 and xampp. I created a folder name CI in htdoc, where all my codeigniter files and folders are , i.e application, system , user_guide, license.txt, index.php and .htaccess(which is blank).

My dreamweaver set up is :

```
Site
Site Name: codeIgniter   Local Site Folder: C:\xampp\htdocs\CI

Servers
ServerName: codeIgniter   Connect using: Local/Network
Server Folder: c:\xampp\htdocs\CI\   Web URL: http://localhost/site/

and i unticked remote server and ticked testing server.
```

My codeigniter set up is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site/';
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
and created site.php in the controller.
```

Error i am getting in dreamweaver is :
    Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site defination is not
    correct for this server.Retry|Setup.

Also when i am trying to view it as Live View or in browser it is taking me to 
localhost/site/application/controllers/site.php  , which saying object not found

But everything is fine using notepad++ though and i can see nothing is wrong in setting up codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Your weburl must match your site root, change your weburl and `$config['base_url']` to `http://localhost/CI/` and also check that your server model is set to php/mysql.

Comment: ok ,  now it is not showing the error , but now it is saying No direct script access allowed , if i try to preview the page via dreamweaver preview in browser option , because it is taking me to localhost/CI/application/controllers/site.php. But if i manually put localhost/CI/index.php/site/home in the browser i can see the page

Comment: Yes that's how it's supposed to work, all request flow through the index.php page. Check http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html